# How to disable Protected Mode in Internet Explorer 7?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, protected-mode

The server has some options disabled and I need to enable it on 1 PC via 3rd party software or registry hack. How can I verify that it's disabled?

I am an IT Administrator so I can't disable the policy for all users

Answer (score 1):

> " To verify that Internet Explorer is running in Protected mode, look for the words "Protected Mode: On" next to the Web content zone displayed in Internet Explorer's status bar."

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#upm_cfgpm)

[Also See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537187%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: how do I turn it on or off (via 3rd party software or registry hack)

Comment: @CocoaDev Found this, not sure if it works for your OS or not...http://www.itedge.net/blog/2007/08/08/disable-ie7-protected-mode-on-windows-server-2008/